# Alter PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm need an array of all the folders in a directory, im using laravel to get an array of folders in the directory using the below code.

`Storage::allDirectories('/public');`

this returns an array like below.

```
$directories = [
    "Gallery",
    "Images",
    "Images/Proof",
    "Images/Proof/Another",
];
```

I need a way to remove duplicate parent directories, so for example `Images` will be remove if `Images/Proof/Another` exists or something like that, i just need to build an array of a directory and its subfolders as one array, if that makes sense.

so for example:

```
$directories = [
    ["Gallery"],
    ["Images/Proof/Another"],
];
```

Or something like this, I can't think of a way to get this to work.

I'm building a custom media manager component if anyone was wondering, some exist but i have no control over them so i built my own.

all **help** is appreciated.

**Can you post the code you have tried so far**

For 1 i can't get my head around the logic, thats why im asking what i've done "Which i dont see how it would help at all"

```
foreach (Storage::allDirectories('/public') as $folder)
{
    $all_folders[] = $exploded('/',$folder);
}
```

Im trying to separate the array into smaller arrays and check each exploded bit against another. But this has me running in circles.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: @NigelRen literally no idea how this would help, im stuck figuring out the logic to do this, But i've updated it anyway

Comment: Showing you have tried something indicates your not just someone who can't be bothered and is happy to let others do the work for them.  Some people will downvote a  question because of this (don't know in this case - but you can see it does happen) - I prefer to ask.

Comment: @NigelRen I was thinking through the logic like i said, and couldn't come up with something. I didn't run into this error and immediately come to stack I've been thinking but couldn't come up with something so i decided to finally ask. But I dont know how to show my thinking when everything I've thought through doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rsort (descending) it and foreach it you can then use preg_grep to see if it exsists in your new array.
If not add it.

```
$directories = [
"Gallery",
"Images",
"Images/Proof",
"Images/Proof/Another",
];

Rsort($directories);
$new=[];
Foreach($directories as $val){
    If(!preg_grep("~" . $val. ".*~",$new)){
        $new[] = $val;
    }
}

Var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/0EnZ3

Preg_grep will look for the pattern and see if it exsists in the array.
Since I loop descending it will first look at `Images/Proof/Another` then add it to the list because it's not there.
Next iteration will look at `Images/Proof/` and since preg_grep has pattern `Images/Proof/.*` it will be true thus not add it in the list.
Then the same with images.

Comment: Thank you for answering ive been trying to get an answer for an entire day but just get slated for my question asking abilities lol. Ill have to look up Rsort + preg_grep, but thank you for this

Comment: This is a good solution, I like the reverse sorting aspect. However really have to ask why you are capitalising the first letter of functions / control structures.

Comment: @Mark it's because most of my answers are written on my phone and it auto capitalize each new "sentence". I have not managed to learn it PHP that well yet ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Do like below (***Easiest way***):-

```
$final_array = [];

foreach($directories as $dir){
  $final_array[explode('/',$dir)[0]] = $dir;

}
$final_array =array_values($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/912417

***Or:-***

```
$final_array = [];

foreach($directories as $dir){
  $final_array[explode('/',$dir)[0]][0] = $dir;

}
$final_array =array_values($final_array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/912418

Comment: What if not only the zero depth directory is a duplicated parent?

Comment: @shukshin.ivan  OP din't address that

Comment: It wouldn't make sense that there is a duplicate on the first level.

Answer (score 1):

You can just filter array using `array_filter` function.

```
<?php
$directories = [
    "Gallery",
    "Images",
    "Images/Proof",
    "Images/Proof/Another",
];

$filtered = array_filter($directories, function($v) use ($directories) {
  foreach($directories as $dir) {
        if(strpos($dir, $v . "/") === 0) {
          return false;
        }
  }
  return true;
});
var_dump($filtered);
```

Not so elegant, but clear to read.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty, but tested and works

```
function removeRedundantParents($directories)
{
    foreach ($directories as $key => &$val)
    {
        foreach ($directories as $i => &$v)
        {

            if ($val !== $v && substr($v, 0, strlen($val)) == $val)
            {
                unset($directories[$key]);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    return $directories;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by removing the row if it satisfies the logic.

Mutative, but satisfies the requirement correctly.

Tested, works properly.

check out https://eval.in/912439 for the snippet and output

**Code**

```
$directories = array_flip($directories);

foreach ($directories as $dir => $key) {
  $parent_dir = preg_match('/(.*)\//', $dir, $match);
  if (isset($match[1])) {
    unset($directories[$match[1]]);
  }
}

$directories = array_keys($directories);
```